# Allow Greenlet to finish work at end of main module execution

Tags: python, gevent

I'm making a library that uses gevent to do some work asynchronously.  I'd like to guarantee that the work is completed, even if the main module finishes execution.

```
class separate_library(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()

    def do_work(self):
        from gevent import spawn
        spawn(self._do)

    def _do(self):
        from gevent import sleep
        sleep(1)
        print 'Done!'

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    lib = separate_library()
    lib.do_work()
```

If you run this, you'll notice the program ends immediately, and `Done!` doesn't get printed.

Now, the main module doesn't know, or care, how `separate_library` actually accomplishes the work (or even that `gevent` is being used), so it's unreasonable to require joining there.

Is there any way `separate_library` can detect certain types of program exits, and stall until the work is done?  Keyboard interrupts, SIGINTs, and `sys.exit()` should end the program immediately, as that is probably the expected behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a new thread that is not a daemon thread that spawns your gevent threads. Your program will not exit due to this non daemon thread.

```
import gevent
import threading

class separate_library(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()

    def do_work(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.spawn_gthreads)
        t.setDaemon(False)
        t.start()


    def spawn_gthreads(self):
        from gevent import spawn
        gthreads = [spawn(self._do,x) for x in range(10)]
        gevent.joinall(gthreads)

    def _do(self,sec):
        from gevent import sleep
        sleep(sec)
        print 'Done!'

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    lib = separate_library()
    lib.do_work()
```

Comment: Works very well, thanks!  I ended up doing something with `atexit` that was so ugly, it feel right to post.